# Getting "Sass::SyntaxError" after trying to install Foundation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation, railsapps

[image]

I'm getting this error after installing foundation and simple form using the last version of the (PDF) book [Learn Ruby on Rails](http://learn-rails.com/learn-ruby-on-rails.html).

I just added Foundation to my Gemfile

```
gem 'foundation-rails'
```

and then run

```
rails generate layout:install foundation5 --force
```

Comment: Could you please provide a code for the partial, that you try to import?

Answer (score 0):

There's an error in the (PDF) book.

You need to change from

```
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
```

to

```
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
```

https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/6148

Comment: The Gemfile listing in versions of the book prior to version 2.1.6 showed gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.1' where it should have been gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'. I've corrected the error in version 2.1.6 of the book. See https://github.com/RailsApps/learn-rails/issues/49